# C++ OpenGL Issue with FBO Not Showing Lighting From Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fbo

I have been tackling this issue for a couple days now. I am not sure if it's a really simple fix or not but I can't seem to fix it. The issue is that my lighting shader functionality works fine if I don't render to a FBO but when I do render the scene to a FBO the lighting shader doesn't work.

**FBO Initialize**

```
//create fbo texture id
glGenTextures(1, &m_fboTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_width, m_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//I have removed this and doesn't change anything
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_fboDepthBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_fboDepthBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, m_width, m_height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

//create fbo id
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboTexture, 0);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_fboDepthBuffer);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

**I bind/write FBO like this:**

```
//I have also used GL_FRAMEBUFFER here as well
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo); 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

//render my geometry here

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

This is what I get without the FBO and how it should look:
[image]

This is what I get when I render the scene to a FBO:
[image]

As you can see, the lighting is not working with the FBO for some reason. What do you guys think? If there is any additional code you want to see let me know. Thanks again for the help!

**Update**

here is how I am rendering my geometry:

**With FBO**

```
if(hasFBOs)
{
    m_fbo->Begin();

    view = m_camera->GetViewMatrix();
    proj = m_camera->GetProjectionMatrix();

    Render3D(&view, &proj);

    view.SetIdentity();
    proj = m_camera->GetOrthoMatrix();

    Render2D(*spriteBatch, &view, &proj);

    m_fbo->End();

    RenderFbos(*spriteBatch, view, proj);
}
else
{
    view = m_camera->GetViewMatrix();
    proj = m_camera->GetProjectionMatrix();

    Render3D(&view, &proj);

    view.SetIdentity();
    proj = m_camera->GetOrthoMatrix();

    Render2D(*spriteBatch, &view, &proj);
}
```

My RenderFbos function just renders the fbo:

```
void RenderFbos(SpriteBatch& spriteBatch, IGSRMatrix4x4 viewMatrix, IGSRMatrix4x4 orthoMatrix)
{
    IGSRMatrix4x4 world;

    m_fbo->Bind(0);

    m_fboShader->BeginShader();
    m_fboShader->SetShaderMatrixParameter("worldMatrix", world.AsArray());
    m_fboShader->SetShaderMatrixParameter("viewMatrix", viewMatrix.AsArray());
    m_fboShader->SetShaderMatrixParameter("projectionMatrix", orthoMatrix.AsArray());

    m_fboShader->SetShaderSampler("texture1");

    float width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    float height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    RecTangle rect = RecTangle(width/2.0f, height/2.0f, width, height);
    spriteBatch.Draw(rect);

    m_fboShader->EndShader();

    m_fbo->UnBind(0);
}
```

**FBO Bind function:**

```
void Bind(GLuint slot)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboTexture);
}
```

**FBO UnBind function:**

```
void UnBind(GLuint slot)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Comment: What are the actual code differences between the correct result and the broken one? I.e, does your "render without FBO" test case still contain the full FBO setup?

Comment: @derhass the only code differences is that one with the fbo has the bind/write and the one without the fbo doesnt have it. I can update the code above in case it helps